# mutate and ifelse in specific columns with NA

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with 6 columns that I want to compare and create a new one, based on the conditions. I'm struggling to use mutate and ifelse, since I also have NA in some places. A small sample of my data looks like this:

```
 dput(test)
       structure(list(value = c(1, 0, 0, 0), value_lag_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 
       0), value_lag_2 = c(NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), value_lead_1 = c(0L, 0L, 
       0L, NA), value_lead_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ref = c(1, 1, 0, 1
       )), .Names = c("value", "value_lag_1", "value_lag_2", "value_lead_1", 
       "value_lead_2", "ref"), row.names = 2:5, class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to compare the 5 first columns against the last one (ref).
If any of the first 5 columns are 1 and ref is 1, then 1, otherwise 0, so my outcome (sim) would be:

```
value value_lag_1 value_lag_2 value_lead_1 value_lead_2 ref sim
    1           0          NA            0            0     1   1
    0           1           0            0            0     1   1
    0           0           0            0            0     0   0
    0           0           0           NA            0     1   0
```

I tried the following, but without success:

```
 myvar <- names(test)[1:5]
 test%>%
          mutate(sim=ifelse( any(myvar!=0,na.rm=T) & ref==1,1,0))
```

Any idea to apply the conditions? Any other suggestion is very welcome.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `ifelse` since all of your conditions are easily inferred with "0" as `FALSE` and "not 0" as `TRUE`:

```
test$sim <- rowSums(test[1:5], na.rm=TRUE) & test[[6]]
test
#   value value_lag_1 value_lag_2 value_lead_1 value_lead_2 ref   sim
# 2     1           0          NA            0            0   1  TRUE
# 3     0           1           0            0            0   1  TRUE
# 4     0           0           0            0            0   0 FALSE
# 5     0           0           0           NA            0   1 FALSE
```

or the literal 0/1:

```
test$sim <- as.integer( rowSums(test[1:5], na.rm=TRUE) & test[[6]] )
test
#   value value_lag_1 value_lag_2 value_lead_1 value_lead_2 ref sim
# 2     1           0          NA            0            0   1   1
# 3     0           1           0            0            0   1   1
# 4     0           0           0            0            0   0   0
# 5     0           0           0           NA            0   1   0
cc(4)
# (converted)
```

Comment: @Jaap, thanks for the edit, but it was inconsistent: the assignment was actually going into `$ref` even though I specified `$sim`, due to the name from `test[6]` (single brackets). Changing it to `test[[6]]` is more consistent. Thanks, I did not see the column name inconsistency.

Comment: Great! that works. I was just using a wrong way! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
test$sim <- rowSums(test[, 1:5], na.rm = T) >= 1 | test[, 6] == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test$sim <- rowSums(df[, 1:5], na.rm = T) >= 1 & test$ref == 1

  value value_lag_1 value_lag_2 value_lead_1 value_lead_2 ref   sim
2     1           0          NA            0            0   1  TRUE
3     0           1           0            0            0   1  TRUE
4     0           0           0            0            0   0 FALSE
5     0           0           0           NA            0   1 FALSE
```

you can convert `sim` to numeric if you really need it in `0` and `1` format.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what you started with `dplyr`, try out

`test %>% mutate(sim = ifelse(rowSums(test[1:5], na.rm = TRUE) & ref == 1, 1, 0))` 
or

`test %>% mutate(sim = ifelse(rowSums(test[1:5], na.rm = TRUE) > 0 & ref == 1, 1, 0))`